# will we miss any cent if 2-decimal currency numbers adding each other?

Tags: calculus

float number is like 2.333, 6432.45645

2-decimal currency float number is like 3.35, 5454.25, 36.15
Ok, now let plus all 2-decimal currency float numbers together, then will we miss any cent?

Comment: You will not miss any cent because cents are added in a rational way.  Rationals are exact.  Cents are in $\frac{1}{100}ths$

Comment: ok, thank you, we only miss if we divide right?

Comment: Divide how?  Please give en example.

Comment: like 10/3=3.333333333 we will never can count enough 3

Comment: If you are doing multiple fraction operations, you will only loose a fraction of a cent if you convert it to float at the very end of all operations.  If you cannot mantain fractions, yes, you will start loosing some cents, but you might loose less if you round it instead of truncate it.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how you are representing the numbers. If you're performing the calculations on a computer and using floating point to represent each value, there is a possibility of precision errors, as numbers like 0.1 cannot be represented exactly using floating point. Computing 0.1 + 0.2 will give an answer like 0.300000000004 instead of exactly 0.3.

Using something like Java's BigDecimal class, you can get exact answers:

```
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal("0.1").add(new BigDecimal("0.2"));
System.out.println(result.toString()); // prints "0.3"
```

...which you can then round off, truncate, etc. as desired. There may also be a "money" datatype (mostly used in SQL) which can deal with the messy details for you.

Comment: so u mean if the computer plus 2  simple number: 0.1 +0.2, there will still have a chance that it will turn to 0.300000004? is that PC error?

Comment: Sort of. The problem arises from the computer not being able to exactly represent the value 0.3 using binary, and must make do with an approximation. The error will be very small - miniscule fractions of a cent - but as more operations are performed, the potential error will increase to significant levels. BigDecimal and the various "money" datatypes store these numbers in a different way that allows for greater precision in these types of operations.

Comment: but why PC can't handle such a very simple calculation that human never make any mistake?

Comment: When a human writes "0.1" on a piece of paper, they know that it represents 0.1. When a computer stores "0.1", it must store it as a binary fraction, which in this case is 0.00011001100110011001100110011001 and then it runs out of space for more digits. However, this binary fraction is NOT exactly 0.1! Instead, it represents something like 0.0999999998603016138, which is very close but not exact.

Comment: Reading the Wikipedia article on floating point may help clarify what's going on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding